# Positioning Bootstrap Modal in Relation to Bottom of Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to CSS positioning and I can't figure this one out:

I want to position the bottom of a modal 10vh from the bottom of the page. In other words, the bottom of the modal should be 10vh from the bottom of the page. I've tried using different "top", "bottom", etc. Values as well as using jQuery to do it programmatically but I started to get lost and recognized there was probably a much simpler way to do it using CSS. Here's the code for the [Bootstrap] modal I'm using:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Testing 1-2-3.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I'd tried that previously, but I was using "position: fixed."  What's the problem with that?

Comment: position: absolute;  thanks!

Comment: .modal-dialog, didn't try .modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` and `bottom: 10vh`

```
.modal { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10vh
}
```